# ¿Por qué me aparece 'Javascript necesita jquery'?

Tags: javascript

Por qué sucede que si voy a un *proxy web* e intento visitar mi pagina web, me aparece `'Javascript necesita jquery'` , como si estuviera mal *linkeado*.

Pero si te vas a la página 
sin estar en un `proxy`, esto no pasa ***y se ve bien la web***, por que?

***Solo sucede con mi web*** y he probado con varios proxies.

***Con proxy:*** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Original***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Bueno era bastante rara la solución y me gustaría saber por qué sucede esto..

***Cambié el link de jquery a este :***

```
"//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
```

y antes estaba la versión 1.2 de cdnjs

***Y lo cambié de posición algo más abajo.***

Encuentro muy raro esto y me gustaría que alguien me lo explicara para así en un futuro no cometer estos errores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En algúnas páginas (en este caso supongo que es: adinplay.com) cuando detectan que se utiliza un Proxy, requieren pasar un Captcha (o directamente bloquean la conexión), si la librería apunta a la página en cuestión, cuando se intenta cargar detecta que hay un Proxy y requiere que se pase el Capcha, como no se pasa la conexión se bloquea, dejándote sin la librería que necesitas.

La solución es cambiar la fuente de la librería o cargarla directamente en tu servidor.